# Searching other classes in java

Tags: java

```
New
| -- test
    | -- Second.java
    | -- Second.class

| -- com
    | -- mypack
        | -- First.java

| -- classes
    | -- expecting First.class HERE

//Second Class
public class Second{}

//First Class
package com.mypack; // Problem HERE 

public class First{
        public static void main(String args[]){ new Second() };
    }
```

CASE 1  : package statement commented in First class

```
C:\Anshul\New\com\package>javac -cp ..\..\test First.java
C:\Anshul\New\com\package>java -cp ..\..\test;. First
Second@19821f
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

CASE 2 :     package statement uncommented in First class

```
C:\Anshul\New\com\mypack>javac -cp ..\..\test -d ..\..\classes First.java
First.java:7: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Second
location: class com.mypack.First
                System.out.print(new Second());
                                         ^
1 error
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Case 1 runs fine. But when I include the package statement in the First class and try to complile it gives error.

Comment: Is your `Second` class inside `test` package?

Comment: No Second class is in a normal "test" folder

Comment: You should move both `Second.class` and package folder of `First.class` inside the same folder.

Comment: You don't understand package naming and it's relationship to folder structure.  First.class must be in com/mypack if its package is com.mypack.

Comment: It wont even let me compile First.java there is no First.class yet

Comment: Remove the -d clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are saying that Second.Java is not under any package, so it is under default package.
Here is the details of what is happening:

> Remove the package statement from First.java

Due to this the First.class too comes into default package and it is able to find the Secon.class in the same package; hence working fine.

> Add package statement to First.java.

Due to this the First.class goes into com.mypack package; but Second.class remains in default package. Hence now First.java can not compile, becuase Second.class is `Not Visible` to First.java code.

In order to solve this, you must import Second class explicitely in First.java. And according to Java conventions, Classes should not be created in default package.

Answer (score 0):

Move your files like this.

```
com
  |
  - mypack
       |
       - Second.java
       - Second.class
       - First.java
       - First.class
```

And now add a `package` statement to the `Second.java` as well.

```
package com.mypack;
```

Now compile them as

```
javac com/mypack/First.java com/mypack/Second.java
```

And run it like

```
java com.mypack.First
```

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this without changing the directory structure ??

Comment: @Anshul Add `package test;` to `Second.java`

Answer (score -1):

You are accessing the First.java in  com.mypack package where there is no Second.java and it is unknown for Java compiler to find the class.
So you must use

```
   import test.Second;
```

at the begining of First.java in  com.mypack package.

Comment: test is not a package, its a normal folder and there is no first.java in the test folder